# Edit meta data does't work with custom sql

Tags: posts, post-meta

I have a form that uploads posts to Wordpress, and at the same time I can edit things like the meta data afterwards.
However using the Wordpress edit_post_data works fine but a custom SQL query won't work. I wonder why.

**Works :** `update_post_meta($edit_id, 'lead_t', $_POST['lead_t']);`

**Doesn't work :**

```
$wpdb->query(
    "UPDATE wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
    VALUES ('".$edit_id."', 'lead_t', '".$_POST['lead_t']."') 
    WHERE post_id = '".$edit_id."' AND meta_key = 'lead_t'"
);
```

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this or debug to find the reason?

Comment: Upadting post meta should be done with `upade_post_meta()`, always. Filters and actions are triggered that will be missed if you do a direct database call; you may end up with unsync data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following...

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->query(
    "
    UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta 
    SET post_id = {$edit_id}, meta_key = '{$meta_key}', meta_value= '{$meta_value}'
    WHERE post_id = {$edit_id} AND meta_key = '{$meta_key}'
    "
);

//or using prepare
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "
        UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta 
        SET post_id = %d, meta_key = %s, meta_value = %s
        WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key = %s
        ",
        $edit_id,
        $meta_key, 
        $meta_value,
        $edit_id,
        $meta_key
    )
);
```

Also as a word of advice, set the following constants in your `wp-config.php` file to enable debugging/error logging.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Errors should be logged to a file `wp-content/debug.log` which should contain any errors relating to your query if it is malformed.

Comment: Should I write {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta instead of wp_postmeta? And is there a reason for this?

Comment: Yes, for example if your database prefix is set to something other than `wp_` your query will not work. Your table prefix is defined in your `wp-config.php` file. If you intend for your code to be portable across installations and or in the public domain, you need to account for the fact that people use all kinds of different prefixes. All in all it's just good practice to use `{$wpdb->prefix}tablename` for compatability. More information can be seen here https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Class_Variables

Comment: I see! What about just writing $wpdb->postmeta?

Comment: That will work because WordPress sets the prefix on core tables, so when you access the class property `$postmeta` it would have already been set to `{prefix}postmeta` prior to access. However it is just good habbit to call upon `$wpdb->prefix` or `$wpdb->base_prefix` depending on which you need for the aforementioned reasons above.

Comment: I see you add the field I want to update as {$meta_key} and the same for value. However I wrote them straight into the query like 'lead_t' and $_POST[]. In your case I would need to define the values separate, but is there any reason I would need to do this? Or is it ok to write them directly into the query?

Comment: You can write your variables directly into the query, that is fine. In my example, I named them so it's clear what they are for any prospective persons in the future that might be reading this it's easier to understand. Also, if it were me, I would leave them as they are and instead encapsulate the call in a function or class method e.g. `wpse_update_meta($table, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)` so that my [logic remained clean and easy to follow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). It almost begs the question; what's wrong with using `update_post_meta()`?

Comment: I see! Thank you very much. I just wanted to learn why some things I try don't work. I'm new to Wordpress and a lot of things are really difficult coming from a php background. Wordpress more than often limits what I can usually do with php because of its write permissions I think. Like uploading pictures through sql forms and stuff. I'm also not sure where to find good guides how to work with Wordpress for people from a php background who usually just write php pages. I often get stuck trying to use and edit data from posts and etc.. Do you have any suggestions for good guides?

Comment: No problem... There's nothing you can't do with WordPress than you can with PHP as WordPress is PHP (and of course JavaScript). WordPress just provides it's own core API to abstract away things that are common tasks. There's plenty of hooks (actions and filters) that allow you to do a lot. Of course nothing stops you from writing your own functions and classes which may or may not make use of core functions. You can learn a lot just by using this site alone (which is an invaluable resource) or refer to the WordPress source code or Codex/Developer docs.

Comment: Cheers! If you have any space time could you have a rook at my other question: What sql / Wordpress queries would need a nonce?

Comment: I'll look, however if this answer helped you solve your problem please mark it as accepted so as it may help others facing similar issues.

Comment: Hey @userabuser Thanks so much for helping me last month. I've gotten a bit better with wordpress functions. I'm still confused about wordpress ajax though. If you have some time could you have a look here? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/205779/how-to-clear-cache-without-a-plugin I promise you can get some rep!